# Virtual Environment- 'virtualenv' is not recognized

Tags: python, virtualenv

`'virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.

Steps that I am following

1. Installing in default directory- `pip install virtualenv`
2. For Create a venv run this `virtualenv -p python3 venv`
3. Activate virtualenv `venv\Scripts\activate`
4. It will look like this (venv) `C:\Users\user\Desktop\UserDjangoProject>`
5. Then run `pip install -r requirements.txt`
6. Run the django project run this `./manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 1):

The `virtualenv` package that can be installed from PyPI via `pip` is geared more for Python 2. If you're using Python 3, you won't need to use this package anymore since the same capabilities are part of Python itself.

To create a new virtual environment do the following:

```
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

At this point, you have a virtual environment ready to use. I would recommend installing `wheel` at this point.

```
pip install wheel
```

Also, some of the packages in a new virtual environment may not be current. If you want to know which packages may be out of date do the following:

```
pip list -o
```

And if you see packages that are out of date, you can run the following command to update everything in one go. This command requires that you have `jq` installed (this may not work properly on Windows).

```
pip list -o --format json | jq -r '.[].name' | xargs -n 1 pip install -U
```

If that command doesn't work properly because you're on Windows, each of the out of date packages can be updated like so:

```
pip install -U <packagename>
```

You will then be able to install Django according to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/install/).

```
python -m pip install Django
```

or you can install the requirements from a file as you have in you list of steps.

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```